# Add a list of items in MyBatis sharing a value in SQL column

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hsqldb, mybatis

I have a `List<MyItem>` that I want to insert via [mybatis](/questions/tagged/mybatis) to a table:

```
CREATE TABLE activities (
  id  BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
  group_id  BIGINT NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(64),
  CONSTRAINT pk_activities PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

- `id` is auto generated / unique
- `group_id` should be unique per `List<>`
- `name` is just a property of `MyItem`

When I insert them I want [mybatis](/questions/tagged/mybatis) **or** the database to make all inserted items share the same (but unique in the database) `group_id` value.

**Is this possible in a single `insert` operation?**
If not - is it possible in 2,3.. ?

**I strongly underline the fact, that either MyBatis OR the database itself (via SQL) can do whan I am looking for**

Comment: And you don't care what the value for group_id is, as long as it is unique and the same for all items of an insert, correct?

Comment: yes, exactly like that. Unique per group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use a free-standing [**`SEQUENCE`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createsequence.html) for that:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE activities_group_id;
```

Even associate it with the column, for documentation and so that it is deleted with the table:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE activities_group_id OWNED BY activities.group_id;
```

The only difference to your regular sequence like a [`serial` or `bigserial`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) column would create automatically: no column default for `activities.group_id`.
Then your SQL command could be:

```
WITH g AS (SELECT nextval('activities_group_id') AS group_id)
INSERT INTO activities (group_id, name)
SELECT group_id, unnest(ARRAY['foo','bar','baz']) FROM g
```

Update:
Where `ARRAY['foo','bar','baz']` is your array of items (names).
Now with ARRAY constructor instead of PostgreSQL specific type cast `'{foo, bar,baz}'::text[]`

This requires PostgreSQL 9.1 or later for the [data-modifying CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING). I use that to avoid multiple `nextval()` calls. We want a single call.

BTW, the syntax in your `CREATE` script is unknown to me (or PostgreSQL). I would have expected that to be:

```
CREATE TABLE activities (
  id  bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
  group_id  bigint NOT NULL,
  name  varchar(64)
);
```

Comment: This is HSQLDB sytnax. I need to target **both** PostgreSQL and HSQLDB (and so does any potential solution)

Comment: @JohanesMatian: I might have guessed so.

Comment: You can use PostgreSQL compatibility mode in HSQLDB, which accepts the CREATE TABLE and the nextVal('activities_group_id'). It also accepts UNNEST, but the array needs explicit ARRAY[...] constructor.

Comment: @JohanesMatian: fredt's information should be good - coming from the tag leader of HSQLDB. I modified my statement to be compatible, accordingly.